# How can I limit a (docker) container resources?

Tags: docker, security, resources, limit, stability

Suppose you want to make sure a container uses as little resources as possible so that whatever happens, it will not affect the host.

*(I do not care if the container crashes because of the limit amount of resources.)*

This is what I already found as possible `docker run` options.
Do I have extra options ?
Are some of them wrong ?

- `--memory=Xm` (with `X` as low as possible, with a minimum of `6m`)
- `--memory-swappiness 0`
- `--cpus=X` (with `X` as something like `0.00001`) *What is the maximum amount of `0`'s here ?*
- `--blkio-weight=X` (with `X` as low as possible, with a minimum of `10`) *Or is it as high as possible ?*
- `--device-read-bps=X:0mb` (with `X` as a device on the host (e.g. `/dev/sda`) )
- `--device-write-bps=X:0mb` (with `X` as a device on the host (e.g. `/dev/sda`) )
- `--expose=0`
- `--gpus=0`
- `--oom-score-adj=X` (with `X` as low as possible, with a minimum of `-1000`) *or should it be as high as possible with a maximum of `1000` ?*
- `--pids-limit=X` (with `X` as low as possible but with a minumum of `1` so that it can run *something*)
- `--read-only`
- `--shm-size=Xb` (with `X` as low as possible, with a minimum of `1`)
- `--cap-drop=X` (I have no idea what you can use for `X` here...)
- Network access should be blocked with `iptables` on the host instead of with a `docker run` option

*(I'm skipping the options that are implied by other options in this list)*

Surprisingly, I couldn't find anything about networktraffic...
Can this be done with `--device-read-bps=X:0mb` and `--device-read-bps=X:0mb` ?
And if so, what is `X` ? *(I don't seem to have something like `/dev/eth0` on my host to represent my networkdevice)*